# jQuery - how to write 'if not equal to' (opposite of ==)

Tags: jquery

I need to reverse of the following code. How can I make the animation run if the width is NOT 500px.

```
$(".image-div").not(this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('width') == '500px') {
            $(this).animate({
                    width: '250px'
                }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }


    });
```

In other words, what the opposite of this?: ==

Thanks

Comment: For your information, you should use `.width()` for this instead of `.css('width')`.  I'm not sure on your box properties, you may want `.outerWidth()`.  Also, use triples such as `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=` most of the time.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The opposite of the `==` compare operator is `!=`.

Answer (score 41):

`==` => `!=`

`===` => `!==`

Equal and its opposite

Answer (score 19):

```
!=
```

For example,

```
if ("apple" != "orange")
  // true, the string "apple" is not equal to the string "orange"
```

Means not. See also [the logical operators list](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jifelse.htm). Also, when you see triple characters, it's a [type sensitive comparison](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html). (e.g. `if (1 === '1')` [not equal])

Answer (score 3):

```
if ("one" !== 1 )
```

would evaluate as `true`, the string `"one"` is not equal to the number `1`