# execute a function if something is not fulfilled

Tags: jquery

```
if ($(this).text != "END") {next()};
```

This doesn't work. `next()` function is executed if `text` is `END`.

```
 if (!$(this).text == "END") {next()};
```

This works, but this is opposite to accepted answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539459/jquery-how-to-write-if-not-equal-to-opposite-of)

So, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).text()` instead of `$(this).text`. It will return the inner text of the tag. Otherwise you are comparing a function to text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using it wrong.. the jquery function text();

try this.

```
if ($(this).text() != "END") {next()}; //note the parentheses
```

Answer (score 1):

The post you addressing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539459/jquery-how-to-write-if-not-equal-to-opposite-of) is all well. you could also follow it like bellow:

```
if ($(this).text() != "END") {next()}; // Or
if (!($(this).text() == "END")) {next()};
```